# check that the give value is the maximum value of a field in a relation

Tags: laravel

I have a hasMany relation named ,A. In controller I want to check whether the maximum value of a field (say flag) from the relation A is same as that of a given value . Flag field has the integer values (0 , 1 and 2)

```
    public function A() {
        return $this->hasMany(table::class, 'id');
    }
```

In controller

I want to check whether the maximum value of a field (flag) from the relation A is 0.

And Want to fetch that condition satisfying data.

Answer (score 0):

**You may call the function max:**

```
A::max('flag');
```

> The query builder also provides a variety of methods for retrieving aggregate values like **count, max, min, avg, and sum**. You may call any of these methods after constructing your query:

Read more on aggregates: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#aggregates